# Adding uploaded files from a directory to a HTML <select> element using PHP

Tags: php, html, while-loop

I'm trying to add uploaded files from a directory to a  form element in HTML.  I'm getting absolutely nothing when I run the page (not even the HTML).  Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>

</head>

<body>

<form name="adgen" id="adgen" method="post">

Choose a Banner Image:&nbsp;&nbsp;<select name="banimg">

<?php

//This variable specifies the file path for the banner image
$filepath="imgdir";

//This variable opens the directory for the correct file path for this select option
$openimg=opendir($filepath);

//This loops through the directory of files and if it finds a file it displays it as an option in the select form element
while($imgsel=readdir($openimg)){

    if($imgsel !=".." && $imgsel !="."){

        echo '<option value="'.$imgsel.'">'.$imgsel.'</option><br />');
        }

    }

closedir($openimg);
?>

</select>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Let me know if you can see what's hanging this up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 Tips:

1. Use a good IDE: [http://netbeans.org/](http://netbeans.org) or [http://www.eclipse.org/](http://www.eclipse.org). Both are good, both would have shown you a syntax error.
2. Turn on errors when you are developing, turn them off when the site is live. Put this on top of the page: `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

The problem in your code was a simple `(`

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ?>
<body>

<form name="adgen" id="adgen" method="post">

Choose a Banner Image:&nbsp;&nbsp;<select name="banimg">

<?php

//This variable specifies the file path for the banner image
$filepath="imgdir";

//This variable opens the directory for the correct file path for this select option
$openimg=opendir($filepath);

//This loops through the directory of files and if it finds a file it displays it as an option in the select form element
while($imgsel=readdir($openimg)){
    if($imgsel !=".." && $imgsel !="."){
        echo '<option value="'.$imgsel.'">'.$imgsel.'</option><br />';
    }
}

closedir($openimg);
?>

</select>
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin, I'll try those IDE's.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like:

```
<?php
$dirContent = scandir('imgdir'); // don't forget to set full path to your folder
unset($dirContent[0]);
unset($dirContent[1]);
?>
<form name="adgen" id="adgen" method="post">
    Choose a Banner Image:
    <select name="banimg">
        <?php foreach ($dirContent as $image): ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $image?>"><?php echo $image ?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error here:

```
echo '<option value="'.$imgsel.'">'.$imgsel.'</option><br />');
```

Note the extra closed bracket at the end of the line. Anyway a good hint is to use [error_reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php) to debug and see what's the problem.